# When calling git.exe within Windows (but not in shell), how can I set the key directory?

Tags: git, bash, intellij-idea, ssh, pycharm

I am using git from within PyCharm in Windows 7.  The git executable in Version Control settings is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe".  It looks for and finds my key (id_rsa) in c:\some\path.ssh.

I'd like it to look in a different path for the key.  I have read that the Windows environment variable HOME is where git looks for the key.  But setting HOME to a different directory doesn't change where git.exe looks.  If I open a git bash shell, I see similar behavior.  ssh from the git shell works fine and also uses c:\some\path.ssh and is unaffected by changing the HOME environment variable.

How can I change the key directory that is used by the git executable?

More info: According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/msysgit/5RiG2D96iHo, git for windows uses %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% as its configuration directory.  So now my question is only how are the values of the environment variables %HOMEDRIVE% and %HOMEPATH% set when I invoke git.exe from PyCharm (IntelliJ)?  Is there a config file that git.exe uses?  I see ~.gitconfig but nothing in that is relevant to those environment variables.

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206923135-How-to-use-a-different-ssh-key

Comment: Does this help ?

Comment: Thanks.  I have used ssh-add in the git shell to add a key location.  I don't see how that fits with wanting to change the default key location when git.exe starts.  There could be some workaround where it runs a batch file in which ssh-add is excecuted instead of git.exe but it seems like git.exe is using an environment variable to locate the default.  I just can't change it.

Comment: Two options,in PyCharm you can chose git executable, for default is set to this git.exe, you can try to change it to your custom batch file. Second option try use https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coresshCommand  example `git config --local core.sshCommand "/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa_foo"`